# modal on the top and i cant change the width

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The modal is in the top of webpage and I cant edit the `width` of the modal

[image]

**css**

```
.modal-dialog {
    width:1000px;
}
```

head tag code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The modal code in the html body tag. is there any wrong in my code ?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="account" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">My Account</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="POST" action="update_account.php">
                <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Name:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="mname" value="<?php echo $srow['uname']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Username:</span>
                    <input type="text" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="musername" value="<?php echo $srow['username']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Password:</span>
                    <input type="password" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="mpassword" value="<?php echo $srow['password']; ?>">
                </div>
                <hr>
                <span>Enter current password to save changes:</span>
                <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Password:</span>
                    <input type="password" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="cpassword">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">Confirm Password:</span>
                    <input type="password" style="width:350px;" class="form-control" name="apassword">
                </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Update</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I make it fixed?

Comment: You haven't shown the javascript code which opens the modal dialog

Answer (score 0):

Most of these jquery plugins have default CSS that they use, which may be overriding your own CSS. You can try add `!important`...

```
.modal-dialog {
   width:1000px !important;
}
```

Note that using `!important` is usually not a good idea but it should at least confirm that this is the issue.

The right way to set width for this plugin though is probably to send it as a parameter when you call the modal. See the API documentation for the `width` parameter:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: `!important`, not `important!`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap for CSS, you could use the `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` classes to change the width of the modal, Eg:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you can use the `!important` to force redimention the modal with, like said @geoidesic.

```
.modal-dialog {
    width:1000px !important;
}
```

More information on [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)